# Input boxes not appearing in browser when added to react render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my `render` function I added this code so I could filter by the amount of effort required to fix an issue:

```
{' '}
        Effort between:
        {' '}
        <input
          size={5}
          value={effortMin}
          onChange={this.onChangeEffortMin}
        />
        {' - '}
        <input
          size={5}
          value={effortMax}
          onChange={this.onChangeEffortMax}
        />
```

When I run my application it doesn't appear in the browser though. Have I done something wrong?

Here is my entire `render` function:

```
render() {
    const { status, changed } = this.state;
    const { effortMin, effortMax } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        Status:
        {' '}
        <select value={status} onChange={this.onChangeStatus}>
          <option value="">(All)</option>
          <option value="New">New</option>
          <option value="Assigned">Assigned</option>
          <option value="Fixed">Fixed</option>
          <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
        </select>
        {' '}
        Effort between:
        {' '}
        <input
          size={5}
          value={effortMin}
          onChange={this.onChangeEffortMin}
        />
        {' - '}
        <input
          size={5}
          value={effortMax}
          onChange={this.onChangeEffortMax}
        />
        {' '}
        <button type="button" onClick={this.applyFilter}>Apply</button>
        {' '}
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={this.showOriginalFilter}
          disabled={!changed}
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: are you defined onChangeEffortMin and onChangeEffortMax functions?

Comment: OK, not sure what was wrong here. I was in the correct folder in my terminal but when I did `cd /path/to/app` then ran my application again it rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's working fine, please check [check here demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-lewin-yh10r)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the correct folder in my terminal but when I did cd /path/to/app then ran my application again it rendered correctly.